# How to add more than one element to my list/array in C# while reading a file, so I can print all on one line per line of the text?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Help me find out how to add the full array i created into one line, It looks like by changing the int to double to big error changes, so for now I just want to try to add everything on the whole line.

It seems when i try to add a array it prints out the name of the array, when i try to print out the array instance name it prints the file pathway, when i add split array[0] it successfully prints the first element in the array. How can I add the whole array and not just the first element?
This is what the text looks like:

regular,bread,2.00,2
regular,milk,2.00,3

This is what I want it to look like after coded

regular,bread,2.00,2,(the result of 2*2*GST)
regular,milk,2.00,3,(the result of 2*3*GST)

This is what I get it(dont need to show regular item cost string):

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
RegularItemCost:
4.4

This is the code I have got for reading and the method and constructors for calculations:

```
            public List<string> readFile()
        {
            string line = "";
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("groceries.txt"); //variable reader to read file
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) //reader reads each line while the lines is not blank, line is assigned value of reader
            {
                line = line.Trim();     //gets rid of any spaces on each iteration within the line

                if (line.Length > 0) //during  each line the below actions are performed
                {
                    string[] splitArray = line.Split(new char[] { ',' });  //creates a array called splitArray which splits each line into an array and a new char

                    type = splitArray[0]; // type is assigned for each line at position [0] on 
                    name = splitArray[1]; //name is assigned at position [1]

                    //<<<-------food cost calculation methods initialized-------->>>>
                    RegularItem purchasedItem = new RegularItem(splitArray); //purchased Item is the each line to be printed
                    FreshItem freshItem = new FreshItem(splitArray);



                    double regCost = purchasedItem.getRegularCost();  //regCost will multiply array at position [2] with [3]
                    double freshCost = freshItem.getFreshItemCost();
                    string[] arrayList = { Convert.ToString(regCost), Convert.ToString(freshCost) };
                    List<string> newArray = new List<string>(splitArray);
                    newArray.AddRange(arrayList);


                    if (type == "regular")
                    {
                        // items.InsertRange(4, (arrayList)); //first write a line in the list with the each line written
                        items.Add(Convert.ToString(newArray));
                        items.Add("RegularItemCost:");
                        items.Add(Convert.ToString(regCost));  //next add the regCost method to write a line with the cost of that item
                    }
                    else if (type == "fresh")
                    {
                        items.Add(Convert.ToString(freshItem)); //first write a line in the list with the each line written
                        items.Add("FreshItemCost:");
                        items.Add(Convert.ToString(freshCost));  //next add the fresh method to write another line with the cost of that item
                    }
                }
            }
            return items;
        }
```

//constrctor and method

```
            public class RegularItem : GroceryItem //inheriting properties from class GroceryItem
        {

            private string[] splitArray;

            public RegularItem()
            {
            }

            public RegularItem(string[] splitArray) //enables constructor for RegularItem to split into array
            {
                this.type = splitArray[0];
                this.name = splitArray[1];
                this.price = double.Parse(splitArray[2]); //each line at position 4 is a double
               this.quantity = double.Parse(splitArray[3]); //each line at position 3 is parsed to an integer
            }

            public double getRegularCost() //method from cost of regular
            {
                return this.price * this.quantity * 1.1; //workout out cost  for purchases including GST
            }
        }
```

Comment: `Convert.ToString(newArray)` is pretty much like `newArray.ToString()`, so your output 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' is the expected behaviour. Please look up the `ToString` method in the docs, as it es essential to understand this! Also keyword: `override ToString()` You are calling `new List<string>().ToString()` and not the lists items `ToString()` method! You'll need something like `newArray.ForEach(x => items.Add(x.ToString()))` - but since i do not really know your desired output, you will need to adapt this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, multiple things. First, while it's not bad to use `Convert. ToString()`, i think is better to just do `. ToString`. Remember all objects inherit from `object` so all objects will have that method.

If you want all the values of a collection to be "joined" into one string beter use `string. Join()`, look at it, you can specify a separatorto use between values. If you just use the `Convert. ToString()` directly on the list it just print the information about the list object itself, not the values inside the list.

Next, if you use `ToString` or `Convert. ToString` with a built-in type like int or double, it will print the number as a string, but if you do it with your custom object or simply with a more conplex object like `List` it will just print the type info. To solve this in your custom objects (like `RegularItem` f. I.) you must override the `ToString()` method an code there what you want to print when the method get called. So you can override the method and put there to print the cost dor example.

Comment: I had tried the ToString but it seems to say cannot convert from method group to string :/

Comment: On the other hand.... I believe the help worked with the string.Join()!!! for some reason it does not seem to like arrays and list :( but anyhow I solved this code for the most part yipeee! now just need to figure out how to add the columns together.

Comment: `string.Join()` should accept both list and array, it accepts any class implementing `IEnumerable<>` And, what do you mean by "the columns"?